# Data is updated in files but last modified time is not updated

Tags: windows, windows-7, log4j

Using log4J we are writing in a log file and when I open the log file , I see the content updated in the file, but when I see the properties listed , the last modified time is not updated. I am not sure its a windows issue or Log4J issue. This machine is windows7 Enterprise edition.

Did anyone face this kind of issue ?
What should be the approach so that we can see the correct last modified time ?
Does Log4J provide synch/flush kind of feature?
I will be greatful if you can comment.
Regards - JE